# PHPRunner: email array , can't personalize message

Tags: java, php

I’m using PHPRunner and I'm trying to create a button to send an email to selected users with personalized body message. I found an example in PHPRunner support page ([Send an email to selected users](http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/email_to_selected_users.htm)) but it is only with an hardcoded message, so I’m trying to modify the example.

I managed to send correctly the email with personalized message if I only select one user, but if I select more than one all of them will receive the same message.

This is what I have now:

```
$emails = array();
while( $data = $button->getNextSelectedRecord() )
{
if( $data["EMAIL_FIELD"] )
$emails[] = $data["EMAIL_FIELD"];
$body = $data["MESSAGE_FIELD"];
}
// send the email
$email = implode(", ", $emails);
$subject = "";
$arr = runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body));

$result["txt"] = "Email were sent.";
// if error happened print a message on the web page
if( !$arr["mailed"] )
{
$errmsg = "Error happened: <br>";
$errmsg.= "File: " . $arr["errors"][0]["file"] . "<br>";
$errmsg.= "Line: " . $arr["errors"][0]["line"] . "<br>";
$errmsg.= "Description: " . $arr["errors"][0]["description"] . "<br>";
$result["txt"] = $errmsg;
}
```

What should I change? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the code that sends emails?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more code. This is just a code snippet I use to make a button in PHPRunner

Comment: I forgot to ask why header of this question says "Java". Can you please amend as this will confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

In the foreach loop you are appending every new email address to one variable:

```
$emails[] = $data["EMAIL_FIELD"];
```

and you are assigning new value to `$body` variable (overriding the old one) in each iteration:

```
$body = $data["MESSAGE_FIELD"];
```

Therefore when you are calling `runner_mail` just once outside of the while loop, you will send same body (from the last iteration) to all recipients (you built an array of all recipients using while loop).

**Solution:**

You need to call `runner_mail` for each recipient (as the body is different). You can achieve it by moving the call to `runner_mail` inside the while loop:

```
while( $data = $button->getNextSelectedRecord() )
{
    // Send only if email field not empty
    if( $data["EMAIL_FIELD"] ) {
        // This no longer should be an array of emails
        $email = $data["EMAIL_FIELD"];
        $body = $data["MESSAGE_FIELD"];
        $subject = "";
        // Email will be sent for each record
        $arr = runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pleasure. Bear in mind there are a few things you can still improve in this code: lines 6 and 7 are redundant as you can use $data array in call to runner_mail(), I would also advise you against sending emails with empty subject.

Comment: In this case I send emails with no subject because the emails are sent to my sms provider (Esendex). Here the email is transformed in sms trough a service email to sms..For me it is an easy way to send personalized sms to my customers. I know that almost every sms provider has API but I'm not a programmer. Thank you very much for your help.